# c# casting to type gotten from typename as string

Tags: c#, casting, types, typeof, gettype

I want to work around the fact that my WCF servicelayer can not handle a generic method like this:

```
public void SaveOrUpdateDomainObject<T>(T domainObject)
{           
    domainRoot.SaveDomainObject<T>(domainObject);
}
```

so I built this workaround method instead

```
public void SaveOrUpdateDomainObject(object domainObject, string typeName)
{           
    Type T = Type.GetType(typeName);
    var o = (typeof(T))domainObject;
    domainRoot.SaveDomainObject<typeof(T)>(o);
}
```

The problem is this does not compile somehow.

I think this is the result of me not fully understanding the difference between

- Type T 
  I believe this is an object of type "Type"
- the result of typeof(T)
  I believe this results in a non-object type version of the type of T (I don't know how to say this exactly)

Comment: `typeof` is a compile-time construct. `typeof (T)` in your case is `Type`. You are mixing compile-time and run-time stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `typeName`: you have to either pass around `Type` instances, or use `object.GetType()` to retrieve object run-time type.

In either case,

```
MethodInfo genericSaveMethod = domainRoot.GetType().GetMethod("SaveDomainObject");
MethodInfo closedSaveMethod = genericSaveMethod .MakeGenericMethod(domainObject.GetType());
closedSaveMethod.Invoke(domainRoot, new object[] { domainObject });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, something like this is quite hard in C#. It's easy to get the correct Type instance from a string, just like you did, but you'll have to use reflection to get the right method.

Try something along the lines of

```
public void SaveOrUpdateDomainObject(object domainObject, string typeName)
{
    Type T = Type.GetType(typeName);
    MethodInfo genericMethod = domainRoot.GetType().GetMethod("SaveDomainObject");
    MethodInfo method = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(T);
    method.Invoke(domainRoot, new object[] { domainObject });
}
```

Comment: "Try something along the lines of" should have given you a hint. The direction I've given will work (it's what Anton Gogolev proposed as well). It's just not copy & paste ready.

Comment: However, just for the curious, I've modified it to compile. It's still the same answer as Anton's though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem, however did this which is a bit messy:

```
if (businessObject is Made4Print.Country) 
  ((Made4Print.Country)businessObject).Save();
else if (businessObject is Made4Print.User) 
  ((Made4Print.User)businessObject).Save();
```

... Loads of others...

```
else if (businessObject is Made4Print.Timezone)
  ((Made4Print.Timezone)businessObject).Save();
```

Will be interested in a better solution.